# @Value can reads, but @ConfigurationProperties can't

Tags: spring, spring-boot, annotations, yaml, javabeans

I'm trying to read a yml file like this.

```
order:
  foo: 5000
  bar: 12
```

and I can read it with `@value`. (I'm using Lombok btw)

```
@Component
@Data
public class WebConfigProperty {

    private Integer foo;
    private Integer bar;

    public WebConfigProperty(@Value("${order.foo}") @NonNull final Integer foo,
            @Value("${order.bar}") @NonNull final Integer bar) {
        super();
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use `@ConfigurationProperties` since the yml file is going to be more complexed. But it doesn't work with `@ConfigurationProperties`.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("order")
@Data
public class WebConfigProperty {

    @NonNull
    private Integer foo;
    @NonNull
    private Integer bar;
}
```

I also added `@EnableConfigurationProperties` in a config class. All annotations in the config are like this.

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { ... })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { ... })
@Import({ ... })
@EnableCaching
```

Error messages are like this.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in {...}.WebConfigProperty required a bean of type 'java.lang.Integer' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.Integer' in your configuration.
```

It seems like Spring can't find the yml file and trying to put null values into the `WebConfigProperty` fields. I don't know why.

FYI, this is a multi-project application using Gradle. The yml file and a configuration class(not written) are in the same project. `WebConfigProperty` is on another project.

**EDIT:**
Based on @Yannic Klem's answer, this two worked.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("order")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class WebConfigProperty {

    @NonNull
    private Integer foo;
    @NonNull
    private Integer bar;
}

//OR

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("order")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class WebConfigProperty {

    @NonNull
    private Integer foo;
    @NonNull
    private Integer bar;
}
```

Comment: I Think the problem is the `@Data` annotation. I provided an answer but I cant verify it at the moment. Tell me if its not the `@Data` annotation

Comment: Try using `@Getter` and `@Setter` explicitly instead of `@Data`

Comment: Could you try with `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "order")` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lomboks `@Data` annotation adds a `@RequiredArgsConstructor`. 
Spring then tries to autowire the arguments to the constructor.

This causes your exception because it tries to lookup two beans of type `Integer`: foo and bar.

`@ConfigurationProperties` should only have a default constructor and getters + setters for their properties.
The properties are then binded to your `@ConfigurationProperties` class by those setters.

Your `WebConfigProperty` could look like this:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("order")
/**
* Not sure about IDE support for autocompletion in application.properties but your
* code should work. Maybe just type those getters and setters yourself ;)
*/
@Getters 
@Setters
public class WebConfigProperty {

  @NonNull
  private Integer foo;
  @NonNull
  private Integer bar;
}
```